# Mecurial: "5 files removed". Which 5 files?

Tags: mercurial

I just did a hg update, and:

```
sourcedir> hg update
20 files updated, 0 files merged, 5 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

hg removed 5 files.  Which 5 files?  Was there a command I could have typed to preview the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know how many revisions ahead you have updated. If your directory was 3 revisions behind its current state, you can find out the details with `hg log -v -l 3`. The `-l 3` limits the length of the report to 3, and the `-v` lists the affected files with each changeset.

Answer (score 2):

Once you **hg update**, it means you applied the latest pulled changes to your working directory.

Before update (and before pull), you can preview the upcoming changesets with an **hg incoming** command that will give you a preview of the changesets you are about to pull.

Also, a quick way to see what was done is simply be looking at the log: **hg log**.

I also strongly suggest you read the manuals and get more familiar with mercurial and its workflows.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hm.  "hg log" shows me changeset/tag/user/date/summary but no information about local files deleted.